# Como fazer um dataframe a partir de um 'nested dictionary' com 4 níveis?

Tags: python, dicionário

Tenho um dicionário com 04 niveis:

```
{
'RACK 01 Cold Suction Setpoint': {'valor_engenharia': -10.0, 'valor_alterado': -13.0, 'sistema': 'COLD', 'importance': array([-13.11196588])}, 
'HVAC 02 Temperature Setpoint FC1': {'valor_engenharia': 25.0, 'valor_alterado': 23.0, 'sistema': 'HVAC', 'importance': array([-13.063596])
}
```

Como transformar em um dataframe? Já vi soluções com json.normalize() ou from_dict(), mas não funcionaram. Obrigado.

Comment: Como deve ser a estrutura do Dataframe resultante?

Answer (score 0):

Se realmente for um dicionario, você pode pegar os dicionarios internos com:

```
import pandas as pd

dic = {
'RACK 01 Cold Suction Setpoint': {'valor_engenharia': -10.0, 'valor_alterado': -13.0, 'sistema': 'COLD', 'importance': [-13.11196588]}, 
'HVAC 02 Temperature Setpoint FC1': {'valor_engenharia': 25.0, 'valor_alterado': 23.0, 'sistema': 'HVAC', 'importance': [-13.063596]}
}

df = pd.DataFrame(dic.values())

#saida
#   valor_engenharia  valor_alterado sistema      importance
#0             -10.0           -13.0    COLD  [-13.11196588]
#1              25.0            23.0    HVAC    [-13.063596]
```

OBS: digo se é realmente um dicionario por causa do campo com array(). Caso seja um json, você pode convertê-lo para dicionário com a biblioteca built-in **json**